# CSS Best Practice - Color Palette

Tags: css, colors

I'm new to web development and I've been working with stylesheets as needed.  My question is, for one website, we have a specific set of colors to use for consistency.  I don't know the hex values well enough to see them and know off hand it's red (or a flavor of it), green, blue, etc.

Would it make sense to have a comment at the top that is a "color reference" for the given site?

Example:

```
/*
 [Site Name] Color Standards
 Red:   Specific #hexvalue for shade of red being used.
 White: #FFF or #FFFFFF
 Black: #000 or #000000
 Yellow: Specific #hexvalue for shade of yellow being used.
 and so on...
*/
```

I have not seen that in any of stylesheet examples around the web or anywhere else.  As one who does not work with stylesheets on an "as needed" basis, I think this would be a good standard.  (I will certainly use it going forward.)  I would understand why someone who works with them constantly would find this useless and would not do it.

Edit: In response to comments: I (poorly) chose to have black and white in there as part of the example, but what I was getting at is why isn't done as a standard.  The design document may not always be available (but I agree that it should).  I wrote this after I started doing web development (which is new to me) and I just thought that something like this would make sense so that *anyone* could come into the stylesheet know what colors to use to keep the colors on the site consistent.  If something like this were done, there would be no need to rely on an additonal resource: the original designer (who might have moved on), design document (which may or may not be available), or anybody else in the office/on the team.

Comment: You can just use the names, so I don't see much of a reason for this.  If you have some specific non-named colors that you use it would be worth noting for reference, but giving the hex values for all of the standard colors seems somewhat pointless.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: See Martin's Answer.  The concept here to make development better for everyone involved.  We have a design person here, but she works on multiple contracts.  To me, it doesn't make sense for me to **have to** trouble her every time I need to do something for this particular account.  Because I choose to do my job well, and not select what _I think_ is the best match, I thought it might be useful to have something like this so that web developers will know what colors are being used for a given account.  I was using those colors as an _example_.

Comment: I'd reserve this for a design document. For a production site indications like this are best removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard for this or yes and no answer, so if you find it helps to keep hex references at the top of your style sheet in a comment, go for it. You're not going to get punished for it.

Comment: Thank you Martin.  I wanted to know why this wasn't a standard.  What I like about it is that when someone comes to the file (either new to the job or the project), it allows for them to keep the standard for a given website rather than going out and doing **whatever**, color-wise.  It's not as if you can just search hex values by color name within a CSS document, you know?

Comment: It would be nice to have colour variables in vanilla CSS, yes. Solutions like LESS try to provide this. But if you have folks updating your CSS file and using any arbitrary colour then you need to slap them around the head ;)

Comment: I didn't want to be the guy needing to be slapped around the head, which is why I was posting this, but the community here seems to be hating my question (-2 score) though.  I'm with a small consulting firm, and am learning as I go.  I just don't want all our color palettes to be in one person's head and when someone comes behind me, I'd like to make his or her life easier.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I'm quite surprised your question was down-voted—I though it was a perfectly reasonable question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good idea, and implmented in LESS you should take a look.

Comment: I will have to Google this LESS business.  Is that different from trying to have as much of the style sheet on as few lines as possible?  (I'm just responding here and haven't Googled yet.)

Comment: I Googled it and in this is case, more is LESS.  This looks really good and could be useful going forward, as I could just declare a variable for a given section and then when I need to change, or a add a section that matches that, I can just copy the variable (or just use the variable itself) and voila!